# Load JSON Data into Document Ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This may sound like a silly question. I have in my HTML page the following added before the close of the "/body" statement in my HTML page:

```
<script src="http://test.com/api/?json=recentstories&callback=myPosts" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like the datas in myPosts loaded into a variable:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var  loadeddata = //load the data here
}
```

or should I use $.getJSON within the document ready function and remove the javascript from my HTML page?

Sorry if this isn't a proper question.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have it working like this:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var data = $.getJSON("http://test.com/api/?json=recentstories", function(data) {
    console.log(data.posts);
});
});
```